# Suggest slot for SSD

Tags: ssd, sata, desktop-computer, pci-express

I have a Lenovo K410.

User guide (see model k410!): https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/desktop_pub/ideacentre_k4_ug_v2.0_aug_2012_english.pdf?linkTrack=PSP:ProductInfo:UserGuide

Images of motehrboard:

[image]

[image]

**Questions:**

1. Will my PC be able to boot from SSD?
2. Which slot is better to use for SSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, it will act just like a tradition spinning hard drive (Mass storage device)
2. You have 3 sata ports on the motherboard, use one of those.

Slots on that particular motherboard are not for hard drives.